# How to dynamically add a directive to all input elements in AngularJS across controllers & modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add a directive dynamically to all my textboxes in all my controllers & forms.
I got a hack from here : [How to dynamically add a directive to an input element in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333911/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive-to-an-input-element-in-angularjs)

but in my case: there are around 200+ forms spread across different controllers & modules & it will be very time consuming to add it everywhere.

Is there an easier or more elegant way to do it ?

**Edit:** What I want to do ?
I want to remove all leading & trailing spaces entered by user in all input boxes.

Comment: activate your dynamic directive only when a controller is activated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular can have multiple directives with the same name, and will apply them all to the element. Create another `input` directive with the desired behavior ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/xvhesf0d/)):

```
  .directive('input', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          return value.trim();
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Your approach is good but the textbox does not reflect the trimmed value.(model does it by default)

Comment: have accepted your answer for the approach. the issue deserves another question..

Answer (score 0):

If you have any common class in your all forms yo can create a controller with that class name

```
.directive('form-class',function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution used by me to solve the problem (Extension of Ori Dori's answer) :

```
app.directive('input', function () { 
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

            if (ngModelCtrl) {

                if (element.attr('type') == 'radio' || element.attr('type') == "file" || 
                    element.attr('type') == "checkbox" || element.attr('type') == "submit")
                {
                    //ignore them                    
                    return;
                }

                element.bind("change", function () {
                    if (element.val()) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val().trim());
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```