# Angularjs : How to use factory globally

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a factory function for some restrict options for all the name fields and I want to use/call that factory globally throughout the application. How can I use the factory globally?

This is my code:

```
checks.factory('pasteOptions',function($event) {
    var clipboarddata = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z.]+$");
    var pastedData = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
    if(pastedData.match(regex) === null) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean globally? On every textbox, on every textbox with a specific attribute (e.g. class="name"), or something else?

Comment: It means I need to use for every textbox in a separate HTML page @rhumbori

Comment: @Prakash don't you want a [directive instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080299/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive-to-all-input-elements-in-angularjs-across-con), which can extend/overwrite the logic for an existing tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in fact trying to extend functionality for an HTML tag, you might want to use a directive instead.

To use a factory throughout an application though, it can be done by creating a module for a factory as such:

```
"use strict";

(function () {

    angular.module('example.module.with.factory', [
    ])

        .factory('pasteOptions',function($event) {
            var clipboarddata = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z.]+$");
            var pastedData = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
            if(pastedData.match(regex) === null) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
})();
```

and to include this factory into controllers throughout the application, declare it as a parameter in the controllers you wish to use it as such:

```
"use strict";

(function () {

    angular.module("other.module", [
        "example.module.with.factory",   // Name of the module with the factory
        "ui.router"
    ])
    // Include the name of your factory as a parameter to the controller
    .controller("otherModule.ctrl", ["$scope", "pasteOptions", 
        function($scope, pasteOptions) {

            // do stuff with your factory

        }]);

})();
```